# Can not add script behavior VisualContainerAsset

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Inspector (for ball sprite)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDwcA.png)[Trying to add the Ball script to "Ball"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHpq7.png)I am creating a BlockBreaker game 2D and whenever I try to connect a script to a sprite it gives me the error: "Can't add script behaviour VisualContainerAsset.The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour."
I have 6 scripts on total and when I try to attach one to a sprite they each give me the same error. Can someone tell me why?
[SCREENSHOT OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyLpi.png)
This is the ball script :

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

public Paddle paddle;

bool hasStarted = false;


Vector3 paddleToBallVector;


void Start () {
    paddleToBallVector = this.transform.position - paddle.transform.position; 

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(hasStarted == false)
    {
        this.transform.position = paddle.transform.position + paddleToBallVector;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            hasStarted = true;

            this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new 
 Vector2(Random.Range(-1f, 3f), 10f); //This is for the ball to bounce randomly
        }
    }



}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D myColl)
{
    if (myColl.gameObject.name == "Rightborder" || myColl.gameObject.name == "Leftborder") //If the ball hits either the left border or the right border
    {
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += new Vector2(0f, 1f); //When the ball hits one of the borders, the speed will not be reduced
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My apologies I pressed next by mistake. The code is inserted

Comment: Did you create the script "VisualContainerAsset"

Comment: No I did not create that script

Comment: Do all your scripts inherit MonoBehaviour like "public class Ball : MonoBehaviour "

Comment: Yes all of them have MonoBehaviour

Comment: Oh wait, you can't attach a script to a sprite, you need to make a game object and then attach a sprite and your script to that.

Comment: It still won't let me for some reason

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: Sorry, I meant of what you're adding and what you're adding it to.

Comment: I have added the other screenshot I hope it had enough details

Comment: Ok, I'm not going to pretend I know what's going on, I need to see some more things to help you. Click on the ball and add a screenshot of the inspector. And add the code for the script you're trying to add to the ball.

Comment: The script cannot be added in any way, unfortunately, no matter what I try the error still pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the file and the class need to be consistent. I.e. if the class is called `Ball`, the file should be called `Ball.cs` or `Ball.script`, I forget what they're saved as.

If that doesn't work, I found this on the unity forums:

[image: Script reset]

Apparently you need to reset the script?

Comment: Thank you so very much ! I finally got them to work ! Thank you !

Comment: Any time, it's my pleasure!